# Помогите настроить SetWebhook для Telegram Api на Laravel и пакетом /irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk

Tags: laravel, telegram-bot, telegram

Уже примерно месяц, не могу понять как сделать правильный setWebhook() для работы Телеграмм бота. Вроде бы всё настраивал, но к сожалению не работает. Если есть возможность - кто может откликнуться и помочь настроить данного бота( через Зум или Скайп ). Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: А это разве подходит под тематику форума?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте https://github.com/westacks/telebot.
Данная библиотека, в отличии от `irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk`. Создает обработчик для вебхука автоматически. Все что вам нужно сделать для установки вебхука, это указать `APP_URL` в `.env` и вызвать команду описанную [в документации](https://westacks.github.io/telebot/#/laravel?id=webhook). Так же есть [команда для запуска long-poling](https://westacks.github.io/telebot/#/laravel?id=long-polling), для работы бота локально.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую и этот!